# Tinting a Xamarin Android ZXing custom view

Tags: android, xamarin, zxing

Is it possible to tint a Xamarin.Android ZXing custom inflated view so that the camera surface appears to be blue or red tinted?

Comment: Just add a blue transparent custom view on top? What have you tried?

Comment: That doesn't let me use the BackgroundTintMode to colorize it with Add/Multiple etc. What I'd like to do is saturate the image so that the detail isn't obscurred, but it's colored with a particular hue. Putting a custom view on top doesn't seem to let me use BackgroundTintMode to blend the color with the camera surface.